# Facebook Invite Friends Dialog box in a page instead of a pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am using the code in this page for integrating the Invite Your friends functionality in my app.

```
 FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request'
        }, requestCallback);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

It always pops out a dialog box for these. I was looking to embed this inside my page inside of having a dialog box. Any suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is there is a display parameter that can be passed with FB.UI ,there is option to use page , iframe etc which helps with it. My colleague pointed out to that one. Good eye there.

Its on this page under the common parameters section
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to embed the app-request in your page, its' only version is dialog, the only things you can embed are the [Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) but none of them offers the functionality you ask for.

According to the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) there are two types of requests the "user to user" requests and the "app to user" requests, the dialog is the first and it can only be used with the dialog.